# Why gyromagnetic ratios of different nuclei are different?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

I have recently started reading about NMR spectroscopy. I know the formula $\mu$ = $\gamma.J$, where **J** is the angular momentum (intrinsic or spin angular momentum) of the particle. I also know the $\gamma$ value of proton and neutron, but with their help how can I calculate the $\gamma$ value of any nucleus ?

Why do N-15 and O-17 nuclei have negative gyromagnetic ratio ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proton and neutron are both spin 1/2 particles, and thus have well defined magnetic moments. For an elementary spin 1/2 particle of charge $e$ and mass $m$:

$$\mu = \frac{e\hbar}{2mc}$$

defines the naive magneton. For a proton (electron), it is called the nuclear (Bohr) magneton, $\mu_N$ ($\mu_B$).

In the lab, a particle's magnetic moment differs from naive moment. The difference is captured with the g-factor. For the electron that looks like:

$$ {\bf \mu} = g\mu_B\frac{\bf S}{\hbar} $$

where ${\bf S}$ is the vector spin. The spin has magnitude $\frac{\sqrt 3}2\hbar$, but the projection on any axis is always $\frac 1 2 \hbar$. Hence the naive g-factor is 2. QED famously corrects this to give:

$$ g_e = −2.00231930436256(35) $$

The difference is caused by higher order interactions with the electromagnetic field.

For the nucleons, the g-factor differs from 2 because of the composite nature of protons and neutrons. They are not elementary particles. The result is:

$$\mu_p = 2.793\mu_N $$
$$\mu_n = -1.913\mu_N $$

The dimensionless g-factor captures the magnetic moment per spin angular momentum, relative to a naive spin 1/2 charged fermion. (Of course the neutron is neutral, so we just use $+e$)

In the lab, it is more common to use the gyromagnetic ratio:

$$\gamma = g \times \frac{\mu_N}{\hbar} $$

which relates the Larmour precession frequency to the applied magnetic field:

$$ \omega = -\gamma B $$

A nuclear magnetic moment arises from the magnetic moments of the nucleons it comprises; however, a direct calculation is often difficult. For instance, take the simplest compound nucleus, the deuteron. It is spin-1, so that for a spin-up deuteron, the spin/isospin-state should look like:

$$\chi_{1,2}\times\tau_{1,2} \propto |\uparrow_1\uparrow_2\rangle[|p_1n_2\rangle -|n_1p_2\rangle]$$

where the subscripts label each nucleon. Here, the spins are parallel:

$$ |\uparrow_1\uparrow_2\rangle =|S=1,S_z=1\rangle $$

Naively, one would expect the magnetic moment to be the sum of the proton on neutron; however:

$$\mu_D = 0.857438228\mu_N = 0.97436(\mu_p+\mu_n)$$

The discrepancy results from D-wave contributions to the nuclear wave function. (We know this because the deuteron has an electric quadrupole moment).

The nuclear wave function is predominately S-wave, or spin-0:

$$\psi^{S} =f_S(r)Y_0^0(\theta,\phi)$$

Here, the total angular momentum comes exclusively from spin:

$$|J=1,J_z=1\rangle=Y_0^0(\theta,\phi)|S=1,S_z=1\rangle $$

Meanwhile, for the small D-wave admixture, the nuclear total spin $S$ is not in an $S_z$ eigenstate:

$$|J=1,J_z=1\rangle=-\sqrt{\frac 3{10}}Y_2^1(\theta,\phi)|1,0\rangle
+\sqrt{\frac 1{10}}Y_2^0(\theta,\phi)|1,1\rangle
+\sqrt{\frac 3 5}Y_2^2(\theta,\phi)|1,-1\rangle
 $$

In larger nuclei, this gets complicated quickly. Moreover, there can be contributions from orbital angular momentum, with a different g-factor $g^{(l)}$.

In the shell model, the magnetic moment for a state $\psi$ is the expectation value of the z component of the magnetic moment operator:

$$ \mu =\langle\psi|\mu_z|\psi\rangle =\frac 1 {j+1}\langle\psi|{\bf j} \cdot {\bf \mu}|\psi\rangle$$

From there, you expand it into contributions from orbital and spin angular momentum:

$$ {\bf \mu} =g^{(l)}{\bf l}+g^{(s)}{\bf s}$$

With

$${\bf j}={\bf l}+{\bf s} $$

you get:

$$ {\bf l}\cdot{\bf j} =\frac 1 2(j^2+l^2-s^2)$$

$$ {\bf s}\cdot{\bf j} =\frac 1 2(j^2-l^2+s^2)$$

which can all be put together into:

$$\mu=\frac 1{j+1}\big(g^{(l)}\frac 1 2[j(j+1)+l(l+1)-s(s+1)]+
g^{(s)}\frac 1 2[j(j+1)-l(l+1)+s(s+1)]\big)$$

(See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_magnetic_moment)

And that's just the shell model estimate. Other considerations in nuclear structure can also effect the magnetic moment. For example, one-pion exchange currents:

$$ n\rightarrow p + \pi^-\rightarrow n $$
$$ p\rightarrow n + \pi^+\rightarrow p $$

and other mesons (like the vector rho, which has its own magnetic moment).